# Prevent subdomain from redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, iis-8

I have the following rewrite rule in my `web.config` when the production transform is applied.

`<system.webServer>
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect-HTTP-TO-HTTPS" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>`

When I deploy a separate website with the staging transform to the same IIS instance, this rule doesn't get added to my `web.config`. Yet traffic to `staging.example.com` still get's caught by the rule.

It seems the production rule is still catching it?

Production url: `example.com`

Staging url: `staging.example.com`

How would I make this rule a little less greedy, so it doesn't redirect staging traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional condition to your rule to ignore staging.example.com:

```
<rule name="Redirect-HTTP-TO-HTTPS" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^staging\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Keep in mind, that browsers often cache 301 redirects. After you applied this rule please clear your browser's cache or use incognito mode

Comment: Thank you! When I add this condition, it throws both sites into a redirect loop - any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you used `MatchAll` for `logicalGrouping` ?

Comment: Ahh you're right, I had `MatchAny`! Thank you so much for your help!